# From class A how to access a method from class B

Tags: php

Given:

```
        $emp = new employee ();
        $err = new errReporter ();
```

How can I have $emp access a method of errReporter, with potentially passing parms. I would prefer not using inheritance as PHP only supports single level inheritance and the above may occur on multiple levels.

Comment: Pass `$emp` to `errReporter` construct

Comment: You could pass `$err` as a parameter to a function owned by `employee`.

Comment: How about a DI approach like: `class ErrorReport { function __construct( string $err_info, EmployeeInterface $reporter ) {} }`